# How to annotate types for columns in sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, pylance

How do I annotate the columns in my model? The following seems to mostly work:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__: str = 'mytable'

    id: str = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    test: int = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    is_valid: bool = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
```

Those type hints such as `id: str` remove the errors but a warning still appears for each column saying:

```
Expression of type "Column[Text]" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
  "Column[Text]" is incompatible with "str" PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

This is Pylance, I messed around with the mypy stuff recommended [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954928/type-annotations-for-sqlalchemy-model-declaration) but it didn't really help and also I imagine I shouldn't be mixing mypy with Pylance (which is pyright no?).

I've also tried for eg. `id: db.Column[Text]` but that seemed to confuse the rest of my code elsewhere...

Comment: As mentioned in the other question you linked, you don't annotate them, you use the stubs package.